# Was -oe- used natively in standard classical Latin, or was every word with -oe- adopted from a foreign or non-standard origin?

Tags: greek, diphthong

Latin has quite a few words with -oe-, such as *Poenus* and *moenia*. But I've heard it said that all of those words are either translitterations from Greek -oi- or adopted from non-standard dialects of Latin (although I thought the Romans seldom passed on a chance to standardise variants, which is why Latin spelling is so uniform, compared to e.g. Greek or Mediaeval Dutch?). Is this true?

Bonus questions:

- Are there other origins of -oe- in Latin than the two mentioned above?
- Was -oe- used more frequently in pre-classical Latin?

Comment: @sumelic: Yes, exactly, standard would be -u- (cf. Poenus, Punicus). But I thought it was just regional, not originally from Rome (so I was probably wrong). I know *one/an* was something with oin- in Proto-Indo-European: so you're saying pre-classical Latin also had this oi- in what would become unus? If so, that would be the stub of an answer to my two bonus questions...

Comment: Rudolf Walter (Walter 1987, *Altlateinische Inschriften*) writes that **oe "was nichts anderes ist als eine graphische Neuerung für altes oi** und in der Kaiserzeit /e/ ausgesprochen wurde" (p. 316). He also argues that when and how this "archaizing" spelling innovation became regular "ist nicht feststellbar."

Comment: Which for those who don't know German means "impossible to determine." :) @AlexB, any chance you could convert this into an answer?

Comment: Sihler par. 59 discusses the origin of Latin oe in detail. The question is debated.

Comment: @AlexB.: Oh, that's interesting. But he doesn't say whether there used to be any -oi- words (before this innovation) that were neither Greek nor dialectical. Or are we to interpret him thus?

Comment: @fdb: Hmm an answer based on Sihler would be interesting...

Comment: Sorry, very busy at work this week, so can't write a real answer now. Weiss 2009/2011 gives a very good summary (in English), see p. 102.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is based on the discussions in Weiss and Sihler.

The regular development is *oi > ū*: e.g. *ūnus* : Gk. οἴνη "one (on a die)". There are inscriptions up until the second half of the 2nd century BC that still show OI, e.g. LOIDOS for later *lūdus*.

However, there are a few words that have *oe* instead of *ū*: e.g. *moenia, poena, Poenus, foedus* "ugly", *foedus* "treaty". In all of these words the *oe* is preceded by a labial and followed by a coronal. (In other words with *oe*, e.g. *coepī, proelium*, the *oe* is secondary and results from the combination of a prefix ending in *-o* with the vowel *e*.) But, apparently it is not a question of simple phonetic conditioning, as Weiss says that "this cannot be the whole story since evidently *oe* did monophthongize in this environment in some words". Examples include some words from the same roots as the words above, e.g. *Pūnicus, mūnīre*. Sihler mentions the theory that the words which retained *oe* are "technical or literary" words, but this does not seem to be true of all of them. Neither Weiss nor Sihler mentions the possibility that these words are loans from a non-standard dialect.

So it looks like there's no complete answer: the outcome *oe* is partly phonetically conditioned, but there may be something more going on that we haven't figured out.

Comment: Excellent answer, merci! I have heard someone say the oe in some words has a dialectical origin, but I don't remember who. It must have been a professor or other university teacher. As to "this cannot be the whole story since evidently oe did monophthongize in this environment in some words", cf. *Poenus, Punicus* and *moenia, munio*: in both cases, we have oe and u from the same root. Only dialect and accentuation come to mind as potentially differentiating factors, besides—don't make me say it—chance.

Comment: Oh, of course you're right about *Pūnicus, mūnīre* being among the exceptions -- Weiss actually mentions these; don't know how I missed it. Editing the answer accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! An *punio*. I'm still thinking of either archaicisms or dialecticisms. Or perhaps those are the same thing in this case. Incidentally, L&S has a few tantalizing bits of information: *foedus, ĕris (for foedus, Ennius wrote fidus, acc. to Varr. L. L. 5, 86 Müll.* — *foedus, a, um, adj. [Sanscr. dhūmas, smoke; cf.: fumus, fīmus, feteo]*. Ablaut?

Comment: *Foedus~fidus* looks like it could easily be an ablaut alternation. The connection with Skt. *dhūmas* seems less clear (etymological notes in L&S are generally not very reliable, likewise for LSJ etc.).

Comment: I was too lazy to get De Vaan...

Answer (score 5):

It appears that while the *oe* diphthong was common among words that came from dialects of Latin and/or Greek assimilations, other words exist that appear to be native to Latin. Take *coepio* ([to begin](http://latin-dictionary.net/definition/10764/coepio-coepere-coepi-coeptus)), for instance. It is a very common word that has been in use seemingly since the beginning of the language. It was used all over, so it is not generally dialect-specific. Although it may have been more common in the sources you mentioned, it was also a natural entity.

Comment: That is a very interesting example! It does seem to be a contraction of *co-apio*, often read as two syllables (*coëpi*) in older Latin, but perhaps that doesn't disqualify it: http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=coepio&filter=CUTF8 I'm having trouble deciphering Lewis & Short's "*v.a.* and *n.*", though. Verbum activum and noun? Vide ante and neuter? Vox activa? The abbreviations: http://latinlexicon.org/LNS_abbreviations.php

Comment: @Cerberus I'm also having issues with those abbreviations... It can't be noun or neuter because those refer to nouns and this is a verb. It also can't be vide ante as that means "see before" which makes little sense in context. Interesting...

Comment: @Cerberus I believe they mean "verb active and neuter", which are old-fashioned terms for transitive and intransitive.

Comment: @TKR: Ahh that does make sense! I should have looked it up.